# Gulp-rev-collector doesn't work properly

Tags: gulp

I don't understand what's wrong with this code. When I run it for the first time, rev_collector doesn't work. I mean: 'rev' and 'clean' works great, but css file name in index http didn't change ('rev_collector').
BUT it works properly when I start it again.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    rev_append = require('gulp-rev-append'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    revCollector = require('gulp-rev-collector'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    revOutdated = require('gulp-rev-outdated'),
    path = require('path'),
    through = require('through2');

gulp.task('rev', function(){
    gulp.src('./src/less/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/manifest/'));
});

gulp.task('rev_collector', ['rev'], function(){
    return gulp.src(['./src/manifest/**/*.json', './www/index.html'])
        .pipe(revCollector({
            replaceReved: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'));
});

function cleaner() {
    return through.obj(function(file, enc, cb){
        rimraf( path.resolve( (file.cwd || process.cwd()), file.path), function (err) {
            if (err) {
                this.emit('error', new gutil.PluginError('Cleanup old files', err));
            }
            this.push(file);
            cb();
        }.bind(this));
    });
}

gulp.task('clean', ['rev_collector'], function() {
    gulp.src( ['./www/**/*.*'], {read: false})
        .pipe( revOutdated(1) ) // leave 2 latest asset file for every file name prefix.
        .pipe( cleaner() );

    return;
});

gulp.task('rev_all', ['rev', 'rev_collector', 'clean']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, I met the same problem.
After I got nothing from this page, I searched a lot.
I fount my problom came from the order the files loaded.

So I use a new plugin:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
```

then, I rewrite the load code:

```
gulp.task('default',['build']);


gulp.task('build', function (done) {
    runSequence(
         ['clean'],
         ['images'],
         ['statcstyles', 'staticjs'],
         ['scripts'],
         ['styles'],
         ['html'],
    done);
});
```

The code make sure that revCollector will always loaded after manifest create.

Then my problem solved.

I hope it helps you.